# Extracting blocks of "adjacent" XMLElements

Tags: pattern-matching, filtering, sequence, xml

I have a file that, when imported as an `"XMLObject"`, returns an XML object that possesses this general structure: (I've stripped the inconsequential junk wrapping the meat of the file)

```
xml = XMLElement["x", {"y" -> "1", "z" -> "2"},
       {
          XMLElement["noThanks", {"junk"}, {"garbage"}],

          "noisyString",

          XMLElement["yes1", {"info1a"}, {"info1b"}],
          "noisyString",
          XMLElement["yes2", {"info2a"}, {"info2b"}],

          "noisyString",

          XMLElement["yes1", {"info1c"}, {"info1d"}],
          "noisyString",
          XMLElement["yes2", {"info2c"}, {"info2d"}],

          "noisyString",

          XMLElement["noThanks", {"junk"}, {"garbage"}]
       }
      ];
```

I am trying to extract blocks of "adjacent" `XMLElement`s according to the pattern

```
XMLElement["yes1", ___], _, XMLElement["yes2", ___]
```

But I am not sure how to do it.

One of the first things that occurred to me was to try `PatternSequence`:

```
Cases[
    xml,
    PatternSequence[XMLElement["yes1", foo___], _, XMLElement["yes2", bar___]] :> {foo, bar},
    Infinity
 ]
(* {} *)
```

As a second attempt, I tried to expand the pattern to include the entire list acting as third argument to `XMLElement["noThanks", ...]`, which partially worked.

```
Cases[
    xml,
    {___, PatternSequence[XMLElement["yes1", foo___], _, XMLElement["yes2", bar___]], ___} :> {foo, bar},
    Infinity
 ] /. {s_String} :> s
(* {{"info1a", "info1b", "info2a", "info2b"}} *)
```

(whereas I'm expecting to grab all `info`-Strings)

**Edit:** One thing I neglected to mention is that I would also like to have the `info`-Strings from the same "blocks" to be grouped, so that the output gathers `infoXa` and `infoXb`, i.e.

```
(* {{"info1a", "info1b", "info2a", "info2b"}, {"info1c", "info1d", "info2c", "info2d"}} *)
```

If what I am asking is clear enough, is it doable with a pattern similar to what I am using? Or is my head in the wrong place?

P.S. Sincere apologies if a duplicate question exists.

Comment: How about `SequenceCases[ Last@xml, {XMLElement["yes1", foo___], _, XMLElement["yes2", bar___]} :> {foo, bar}]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
xml = XMLElement[
   "x", {"y" -> "1", 
    "z" -> "2"}, {XMLElement["noThanks", {"junk"}, {"garbage"}], 
    "noisyString", XMLElement["yes1", {"info1a"}, {"info1b"}], 
    "noisyString", XMLElement["yes2", {"info2a"}, {"info2b"}], 
    "noisyString", XMLElement["yes1", {"info1c"}, {"info1d"}], 
    "noisyString", XMLElement["yes2", {"info2c"}, {"info2d"}], 
    "noisyString", XMLElement["noThanks", {"junk"}, {"garbage"}]}];
```

Extract the bits you want:

```
Cases[xml, XMLElement["yes1" | "yes2", __], \[Infinity]]

(* 
{XMLElement["yes1", {"info1a"}, {"info1b"}], 
 XMLElement["yes2", {"info2a"}, {"info2b"}], 
 XMLElement["yes1", {"info1c"}, {"info1d"}], 
 XMLElement["yes2", {"info2c"}, {"info2d"}]} *)
```

Before moving on to the next step I'm thinking that if you have this example:

```
xml2 = XMLElement[
   "x", {"y" -> "1", 
    "z" -> "2"}, {XMLElement["noThanks", {"junk"}, {"garbage"}], 
    "noisyString", XMLElement["yes1", {"info1a"}, {"info1b"}], 
    "noisyString", XMLElement["yes2", {"info2a"}, {"info2b"}], 
    "noisyString",
    XMLElement["yes1", {"info1x"}, {"info1x"}], "noisyString",
    XMLElement["yes1", {"info1c"}, {"info1d"}], "noisyString", 
    XMLElement["yes2", {"info2c"}, {"info2d"}], "noisyString", 
    XMLElement["noThanks", {"junk"}, {"garbage"}]}];
```

then you wouldn't want the `info1x` returned in your answer?? So the first intermediate step is

```
tmp = Cases[xml2, XMLElement["yes1" | "yes2", __], \[Infinity]]
(*

{XMLElement["yes1", {"info1a"}, {"info1b"}], 
 XMLElement["yes2", {"info2a"}, {"info2b"}], 
 XMLElement["yes1", {"info1x"}, {"info1x"}], 
 XMLElement["yes1", {"info1c"}, {"info1d"}], 
 XMLElement["yes2", {"info2c"}, {"info2d"}]} *)
```

and from here use `ReplaceList`

```
ReplaceList[tmp, {___, 
   PatternSequence[XMLElement["yes1", x__], 
    XMLElement["yes2", y__]], ___} :> Sequence[Flatten[{x, y}]]]

(*

{{"info1a", "info1b", "info2a", "info2b"}, {"info1c", "info1d", "info2c", "info2d"}}

*)
```

Comment: I've updated my `xml` example to be more usable - please let me know if something more concrete would be preferred. I noticed that the `noise` between desirable XMLElements were simply strings. Perhaps that makes things easier with respect to extracting XMLElements with tag `yesX`?

Comment: @user170231 please see revised answer

Comment: "... then you wouldn't want the `info1x` returned in your answer ..." - this is exactly right! I only want those `info`-Strings that are part of those consecutive/adjacent XMLElements containing the tags `yes1` and `yes2`.

Comment: This is perfect for what I'm trying to do. `ReplaceList` is new territory for me - thanks a lot for demonstrating its usage!